# In Azure ML Studio, how to change Environment to register model as MLmodel?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

Using Azure Machine Learning Studio, I ran a job that generated a regression model. I want to use the function 'Responsible AI' to do error analysis.

The problem: I cannot register the model type as 'MLflow', because 'Output must be a folder containing an mlflow 'MLmodel' file.'

I figured that this is probably because my Environment (AzureML-Designer version 54) does not have the mlflow loaded. *(Is this really the cause of my problem?)*

So, I went to look how to change the Environment (to sklearn-1.1 version 26 for example). I have read the documentation and checked the entire  **Azure ML Studio Graphical User Interface** for the setting. However, I cannot figure out how to fix the issue. Your help is very welcome!

*If your answer includes the usage of SDK or CLI, please also explain why it cannot be done in the GUI.*

[image: Output folder]

Comment: There is no output folder containing mlflow model when ran the job?

Comment: Add output folder screenshot

Comment: No, there is no mlflow model in my output folder. See screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain an `mlflow` model, the training script used in the pipeline component should resemble this [script](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/pipelines/2c_nyc_taxi_data_regression/train_src/train.py). However, in Azure ML Designer's `Classic prebuilt` training component, the script doesn't log an `mlflow` model.

[image]

It's not that it only supports different environments, but the script used for training should use  `mlflow` to track and log the models.

If you have a custom training script, use the Python SDK with a command job to train and log the model. Check this [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/pipelines/2c_nyc_taxi_data_regression/nyc_taxi_data_regression.ipynb) for more information.

According to this documentation, `mlflow` is only supported in `Azure CLI` and `Python SDK`.

[image]

The same SDK is used in the training script while building pipeline components.

If you want prebuilt components that log `mlflow` models, consider [Azure ML Designer v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-designer?view=azureml-api-2).

[image]

You can find the training component in the `components` tab, which you can select for training.

[image]